# SQL: Joining to two tables and then using sum() and count()

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables:

school:

```
school_id | class_id | school_location
-------------------------------------------
400             50               Arizona
```

staff:

```
staff_id | forename | school_id | wage
------------------------------------------
1           Peter          400         5000
```

How could I get the output the number of staff that work in school and the salary of each school.

For example:

```
school_id | numberofstaff | salary
---------------------------------------
400 |           1         | 5000
```

I know I should join the tables like so:

```
SELECT school_id 
FROM school 
INNER JOIN staff
ON school.school_id = staff.school_id
```

However I am unsure how to do the remaining part of the query.

```
SELECT numberofstaff COUNT(numberofstaff) from staff
GROUP BY school_id
Union all 
select 'SUM' numberofstaff, COUNT(numberofstaff)
FROM staff
```

This should give me my school ids with the number of staff belonging to each school_id.

Answer (score 1):

Once you join both tables, you can then count the staff and sum all the wages for each school:

```
SELECT sc.school_id, 
   COUNT(*) as numberofstaff,
   SUM(st.wage) as salary
FROM school sc
INNER JOIN staff st
ON sc.school_id = st.school_id
GROUP BY sc.school_id
```

Comment: So would this select query just go beneath my join statement?

Comment: No, this query would be the whole thing to execute.

Comment: Ah it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
SELECT COUNT(staff.numberofstaff) as numberofstaff , school.school_id as school_id FROM school 
INNER JOIN staff
ON school.school_id = staff.school_id
GROUP BY school.school_id;
```